# `Return` gives wrong json data in output

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to send JSON data from a django rest framework API but the output is modified by the `return Response`

The API:

```
class TransportDirectoryAPIView(APIView):


    def get(self, request, format=None):
        state = request.GET["state"]
        city = request.GET["city"]
        data = pd.read_csv(r"Suppliers.csv", error_bad_lines=False)
        data = data.fillna("-")
        data = data[(data["State"]==str(state)) & (data["City"]==str(city))].reset_index().to_json(orient='records')
        print("data ", data)

        return Response(data)
```

now the print gives the following output:

```
data  [{"index":296,"Id":297,"Company Name":"ABC","Contact Person Name":"ABC",
"Primary Contact Number":"999",
"Contact Number 1":9999,
"Contact Number 2":"-",
"Contact Number 3":"-",
"Contact Number 4":"-",
"Primary Email":"-",
"Secondary Email":"-",
"Address":"ABCDE","City":"ABC","Pin Code":"-","State":"ABC","Services":"SXYZYZYZ"},....]
```

But when I check in Postman it seems like this:

```
  "[{\"index\":296,\"Id\":297,\"Company Name\":\"abc\",\"Contact Person Name\":\"abc\",
\"Primary Contact Number\":\"9999\",
\"Contact Number 1\":9999,
\"Contact Number 2\":\"-\",
\"Contact Number 3\":\"-\",
\"Contact Number 4\":\"-\",
\"Primary Email\":\"-\",\"Secondary Email\":\"-\",\"Address\":\"ABC\",\"City\":\"ABC\",\"Pin Code\":\"-\",\"State\":\"ABC\",\"Services\":\"XYZYXY\"},..
```

Why the backslashes are added to the output and how can I correct it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning text, and not json. This can happen for multiple reasons:

- Are you specifying the `content-type` header in your request? Make sure you are specifying `application/json`
- Also, take a look a the [Parsers page](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/) in the docs. Check your config for the default cases.

Answer (score -1):

You are returning a string hence the special characters are escaped to be used in the string. Try:

```
return JsonResponse(data)
```

or

```
return Response(data, content_type="application/json")
```